# JavaFX8 node resize handles

Tags: resize, javafx-8, handles

I have a StackPane to which I add child panes. Each child has MouseEvent handlers to drag it around the StackPane. Works fine. Then I also want to be able to resize that pane. So I added 8 small 'drag' panes to the child in the appropriate places each with its own clicked/drag handlers.

The problem: once a 'drag' pane mouse event fires, I need to set an anchor point for the parent pane. This anchor point will depend on which 'drag' pane was clicked. How do I identify which pane was clicked in the handler? I suspect I am missing something very obvious, but I cannot see it (Google provides no answers).

I tried using the hashcode, but no luck.

Comment: You probably need to post some code to show what you're doing. If you're registering the mouse handlers with the drag panes, then you already have a reference to the relevant drag pane available.

Comment: Coming from a C background (that's without the ++) I assigned the same handler for all panes in expectation of using a switch() to handle the different panes, but maybe eight different handlers is a better way to go. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I (almost) always prefer to use a different handler for each node, rather than accessing the event source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally realised what the solution was after Googling a different issue. I had tried event.getSource(), but couldn't relate the returned object to my pane. The solution is simply to **cast** it (Panel)event.getSource() it and then it's all go! Talking about dim!